# How to speed up lookup of multi-valued valued attributes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created the following nodes in neo4j (1 million of them):

```
CREATE (p:Person { name: 'user1', email: ['user1@gmail.com', 'user1@yahoo.com'] }) RETURN p
CREATE (p:Person { name: 'user2', email: ['user2@gmail.com', 'user2@yahoo.com'] }) RETURN p
...
CREATE (p:Person { name: 'user1000000', email: ['user1000000@gmail.com', 'user1000000@yahoo.com'] }) RETURN p
```

I have created the following indexes:

```
CREATE BTREE INDEX i1 FOR (n:Person) ON (n.name)
CREATE BTREE INDEX i2 FOR (n:Person) ON (n.email)
```

With the above data, the following query takes 2ms to complete and I can concurrently execute about 2800 such queries per second on my desktop.

```
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.name = 'user10' RETURN DISTINCT p.name
```

But the following query takes 710ms to complete and I can concurrently execute only about 5 such queries per second on my desktop.

```
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE 'user10@gmail.com' IN p.email RETURN DISTINCT p.name
```

Is there any way to speed up the second query and also increase the throughput ?

**Edit 1**:

I tried to use separate nodes for email as suggested by @jose_bacoy in his answer.

I created the following nodes:

```
CREATE (m1:mail { email: 'user1@gmail.com' })
CREATE (m2:mail { email: 'user1@yahoo.com' })
CREATE (p:Person { name: 'user1' })
CREATE (p) - [:attribute] -> (m1)
CREATE (p) - [:attribute] -> (m2)
RETURN p
...
CREATE (m1:mail { email: 'user1000000@gmail.com' })
CREATE (m2:mail { email: 'user1000000@yahoo.com' })
CREATE (p:Person { name: 'user1000000' })
CREATE (p) - [:attribute] -> (m1)
CREATE (p) - [:attribute] -> (m2)
RETURN p
```

and indexed them as follows:

```
CREATE BTREE INDEX i1 FOR (n:Person) ON (n.name)
CREATE BTREE INDEX i2 FOR (n:mail) ON (n.email)
```

The speed is also good. Latency: 4ms, throughput 1850 queries per second.
The problem with this is that the following query performs very badly.

```
MATCH (p:Person) - [:attribute] -> (m1:mail)
MATCH (p) - [:attribute] -> (m2:mail)
WHERE m1.email = 'user10@gmail.com' OR m2.email = 'user10@yahoo.com'
RETURN DISTINCT p.name
```

On my desktop, the latency is about 5s and the throughput is less than 1 per second.

**Edit 2:**

I modified the query as suggested by Charchit Kapoor below. Following is the query I used.

```
MATCH (p:Person) - [:attribute] -> (m:mail)
WHERE m.email IN ['user10@gmail.com', 'user10@yahoo.com']
RETURN DISTINCT p.name
```

has a latency of about 4ms and throughput of about 2600 queries per second.

Comment: How many emails a user can have?

Comment: You can refactor emails into separate nodes

Comment: @CharchitKapoor in this example each user has just two. I intend to apply the solution for this problem in my application where there are multi-valued attributes with varying number of values.

Comment: @TomažBratanič do you mean a separate node for each email value ? In this case, each user node related to two email nodes ?

Answer (score 2):

Your data model is not aligned to your query. Email is a list of emails in Person node and you are searching within a list. Below is a script to change your data model from Person.email into a relationship between Person -[:HAS_EMAIL]-> Email.  The APOC function iterate will divide your Person nodes into batches and will run it in parallel for efficiency. Ensure that you have APOC installed.

Then it will create the (Person)->(Email) relationship and remove the property in Person after completion.  You can change the batch size (10k per batch) according to your taste. You also want to create a unique index for Email.  I will leave it up to you on how to do it.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p as person;", 
"WITH person
UNWIND person.email as email
MERGE (e:Email {email: email})
MERGE (person)-[:HAS_EMAIL]->(e)
SET person.email = null;", 
{batchSize:10000, parallel:true, retries:3});
```

After doing this and creating the index on Email.email, profiling shows that the BTREE index is being used:

```
PROFILE MATCH (p:Person) -[:HAS_EMAIL] -> (e:Email)
WHERE e.email = 'user10@gmail.com'
RETURN DISTINCT p.name

BTREE INDEX e:Email(email) WHERE
email = $autostring_0
```

Previously, it shows NodeLabelByScan and Filter on $autostring_0 IN p.email. Even if you create an index on a list, it is not used.

Comment: I have tried this and updated my findings in the question itself under 'edit 1'.

Comment: your query can be further tuned by using one MATCH statement and one WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your second query can be structured differently, first find all the relevant emails and then find the related users:

```
MATCH (m1:mail)
WHERE m1.email IN ['user10@gmail.com', 'user10@yahoo.com']
MATCH (p)-[:attribute]->(m1)
RETURN DISTINCT p.name
```

Comment: That solved my problem. This query - `MATCH (p:Person) - [:attribute] -> (m:mail)
    WHERE m.email IN ['user10@gmail.com', 'user10@yahoo.com']
    RETURN DISTINCT p.name` has a latency of about 4ms and throughput of about 2600 queries per second. Thanks.